# playing a halfway loaded sound buffer while fast loading the rest of it in C++

Tags: c++, file, buffer

I'm loading parts of sounds in pre buffers at application start up and when a user clicks one of many buttons the pre buffer is starting to play and at the same time it also starts through a thread to load the rest of the sound in a post buffer, when the pre buffer is running out it starts to play the new fresh loaded post buffer. The problem is that the post buffer loading does not complete before it tries to play it.

The question here is, what is the fastest way to load a sound into memory from the hard drive in C++ on Windows?

Are there any great algorithms to succeed with faster loading or a better faster function than the fstream:

```
fstream myFile (fileName, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
myFile.read(...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Threads and a ring buffer? One thread plays the sound from the next buffer in the ring, while another thread loads into the ring.